# How to make local appsettings development json values used by localhost?

Tags: .net-core, environment-variables, development-environment, asp.net-core-6.0, appsettings

I have the following config in my .net Core 6.0 app:

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:33501",
      "sslPort": 44301
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Umbraco.Web.UI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44301;http://localhost:33501",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }      
    }
  }
}
```

The I have **`appsettings.json`** with db `ConnectionString`, eg. "myDb" and **`appsettings.Development.json`** with db `ConnectionString`, eg. "myDb1".

The problem is that `appsettings.json` value is always used.

On startup I can see from `IWebHostEnvironment` values that both files are optional.
Although

```
env.IsDevelopment()
```

is true
and the

```
env.EnvironmentName
```

is "Development"

How to make appsettings.Development.json values to be used on localhost?

I have tried to find an answer onine but so far none of the advices helped.

Comment: appsettings.{Environment}.json values would override keys in appsettings.json by default,could you share a minimal example that could reproduce the issue ,so that we could know why it doesn't perform as expected?

Comment: I think I wrongly used appsettings.Development.json for web server test site and got its settings wrong because of this and this affected localhost. Now the development environment is working but the web server is not seeing appsettings.Staging.json settings :(